# How can I disable the linking for figures in LyX?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lyx

I am currently writing a document in LyX and I'm using hyperref to have links in the ToC, citations etc. The problem is that I added a figure (with float) and when I make a cross-reference in the text, the reference itself becomes a link that leads to the page that contains the actual figure. For example:

```
------Sample Graphic-------

Figure 1.1: Example of a graphic
```

And in the text that follows:

```
As we can see in figure 1.1 there is...
```

Now if I hover the mouse over 1.1 there is a link pointing to the location of the actual figure. Is there any way to disable the links for figures? Perhaps using "hypersetup" or a renewcommand...?

Comment: Would yo like to disable links for tables also, perhaps for cross-references in general?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I think so, however as I'm not sure on the tables yet can you perhaps give the solution to each case?

Comment: I think it would be consistent to do it for all cross-references or for no one. Otherwise a reader might wonder why he can click on `table 1.1` and `equation 1.1` but not on `figure 1.1`, assuming a mistake.

Comment: @Caramdir
Well I'm following instructions as to how I have to write it so... :-P

@Stefan
Thanks a lot for the answer, works like a charm. However I want to ask (mostly out of curiosity) how could I have done that for figures only?

Comment: Doing it just for figures might require some lines of code. I guess there's no easy feature other than using `\ref*`. If you need it, perhaps come back here and we might work it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the starred form `\ref*` to suppress the link. If you want to suppress all links for cross-references in your document, you could write

```
\makeatletter
\let\ref\@refstar
\makeatother
```

after `\begin{document}`. With LyX that means, insert it as ERT at the beginning of your document.

Note, this definition wouldn't work this way in the preamble because hyperref makes changes after the preamble. So, it might be done with `\AtBeginDocument{...}` after loading hyperref but I guess the simple solution may be sufficient.

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to put something similar in the preamble but that explains it. Thank you.